# Build Fails When Running "./gradlew genSources"

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am following the Workspace Setup video in the Kaupenjoe 1.20 Fabric modding tutorial. When I run `./gradlew genSources` , The build fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/User/Desktop/Mods/Fabric-Tutorial-1.20.X/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.4-SNAPSHOT']
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Cannot invoke "org.gradle.cache.FileLock.writeFile(java.lang.Runnable)" because the return value of "org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.access$300(org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator)" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 519ms
```

I've tried changing the version of Fabric Loom, (although I may have done this wrong) and I rewatched the whole video to make sure I set up the workspace correctly until this point. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my Fabric loader version in my gradle.properties didn't match that in Fabric.mod.json.